# How do you make a discord bot respond without commands (but in python)?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a bot in discord that, when you send it a string of some sort, or an event happens, it'll send a message to a discord channel. However, when I tried adding an "input" function (the simplest there is), it couldn't work at all. What other ways are there to input strings into programs like this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. I suggest you improve the question by providing more clear examples. What "input", what "event", send a string how? Also, include a reproducible code snipped that clearly shows what you're struggling with

Answer (score 0):

You can use webhooks to do this.

First, you should install the `discord_webhook` module by running `pip install discord_webhook` into the terminal.
Now, you can write your program. This is a very simple example:

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook

url = # Put webhook url here...
webhook = DiscordWebhook(url=f'{url}', content=input('Enter a message: '))
response = webhook.execute()
```

You should replace the `url` variable with your webhook link. In case you don't know how to get a webhook link, this is an example on how to do it:

[image: example]

Answer (score -1):

If you don't know anything about discord bots, freeCodeCamp did an amazing video on it. Look that up. They are amazing.

Comment: That video helped me so much